# URL is adding automatically - Django

Tags: python, django, rest, url

I have got a problem while redirecting to the edit form.
SO what I am doing is that whenever user clicks on edit button it redirects to `"editadmin/{{admin.id}}"` using `form action = "editadmin/{{admin.id}}"` in HTML.


URL path is

```
path("editadmin/<int:id>", views.editadmin, name="editadmin")
path("update/<int:id>", views.updateadmin, name="updateadmin")
```

Views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def editadmin(request, id):
    admin = Admin.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, "editadmin.html", {"admin": admin})

@csrf_exempt
def updateadmin(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        admin_id = request.POST["admin_id"]
        admin_id = str(admin_id).strip().upper()

        name = request.POST["name"]
        name = str(name).strip()

        
        if db_name equals to name:
            messages.error(request, "Admin name already exists")
            return redirect("editadmin/" + str(id))
```

editadmin.html

```
    <form method="post" class="post-form" action="/update/{{admin.id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" required maxlength="20" value="{{ admin.id }}"/>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><h4 style="margin-left:40px">Admin ID : </h4></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="admin_id" required style="margin-left:20px; height:38px; width:300px;
                        border-radius: 5px" id="admin_id" value="{{ admin.admin_id }}"/>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><h4 style="margin-left:40px">Name : </h4></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" name="name" style="margin-left:20px; height:38px;
                        border-radius: 5px; width:300px" required id="name" value="{{ admin.name }}"/>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:210px">Submit</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

So what I want is that Whenever user submits invalid name in editadmin.html (URL - `editadmin/1` ), it should redirect to the same URL `editadmin/1` but what it does is it appends `update/` which redirects to `update/editadmin/1`
How to fix this? I dont want `update/` to get appended after redirecting to same form.

Comment: My suggestion here is you should use url namespace while url redirect `return redirect('editadmin', id=id)`. otherwise you can append a slash `/` before actual redirection url like this `return redirect(f'/editadmin/{id}')`.

Comment: @Jeet Thank you so much for this. It is working now

Answer (score 0):

`update/` is appending because you mentioned your form action to this URL. So instead of mentioning action in your form, you can do something like this.

```py
@csrf_exempt
def updateadmin(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        admin_id = request.POST["admin_id"]
        admin_id = str(admin_id).strip().upper()

        name = request.POST["name"]
        name = str(name).strip()

        # asuming you are checking if admin with this name already exists in database
        if db_name equals to name: 
            messages.error(request, "Admin name already exists")
            return redirect("editadmin/" + str(id))
        # It mean user enter a unique name
        else:
            # your logic to save the incoming user here.
            message.success(request, "Your success message")
            return redirect(f'/update/{admin_id}')
```

and make sure to update your **form** from this:

```html
<form method="post" class="post-form" action="/update/{{admin.id}}">
```

to this:

```html
<form method="post" class="post-form" action="">
```

Comment: One question, if `"/update/{{admin.id}}"` is not put in action then how will it call the URL path `path("update/<int:id>", views.updateadmin, name="updateadmin")` ?

Comment: I have found my solution btw. But thank you for putting effort in this question